# Adding strings to each element in a list - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list `['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Orange'...]`

I want to add multiple custom strings to every element of the list while keeping the initial ones if that makes sense.

Here is how the end goal of the list will look like:

`['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Orange', 'Apple123', 'Pineapple123', 'Orange123' 'ABCApple', 'ABCPineapple', 'ABCOrange']`

So I want to add custom strings like "123" and "ABC" in front or behind each element without removing the previous elements.

What will be the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of list comprehensions should do the trick:

```py
lst =  ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Orange']
result = lst + [x + '123' for x in lst] + ['ABC' + x for x in lst]
```

**EDIT:**
To answer the question in the comments, if you have many of these transformations, one approach could be to create a list of them as format strings, and then use a nested list comprehension to apply all the of them to all of the elements of the original list:

```py
lst =  ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Orange']
formats = ['{}', '{}123', 'ABC{}']
result = [f.format(x) for f in formats for x in lst]
```

Comment: I see this works, but i need to add like 30 of these "123", "ABC" what will be good way to implement it on such scale?

Comment: Is it always going to be aternate? (One as prefix, one as suffix)

Comment: @50yearoldnewbie one approach could be to have a list of format strings, and apply them with a nested list comprehension - see my edited answer for details

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
new_list=old_list+[e+'123' for e in old_list]+[e+'abc' for e in old_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something more generic where you can easily change custom strings:

```
custom_strings = [
    ('123', 'post'),  # post - append 
    ('ABC', 'pre')     # pre  - prepend
]

lst =  ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Orange']
result_lst = lst 

for cs in custom_strings:
    if cs[1] == 'post':
       result_list.extend([x+cs[0] for x in last])
    else:
       result_list.extend([cs[0]+x for x in last])
```